# Express http 2 server push

Tags: node.js, http, express, google-chrome-devtools, http2

I've made a small server to try http2 on node, however I can't tell if the push mechanism is working or not. My style is loaded over http2 but that does not mean that push is working as intended...

```
const port = 3000
const spdy = require('spdy')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Link', '</css/styles.css>; rel=preload; as=style');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/server.key'),
    cert:  fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/server.crt')
}

spdy.createServer(options, app).listen(3000);
```

In the devtools, the initiator says : "other".

Comment: try using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin) in the chrome
blue means spdy, red means http1.1, green means quic

Comment: @alpheus http2 is working, I can see that in the devtool network protocol column. However there is no mention of push. There is no mention of it in your extension either (it's blue for me btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell your express server which resources to push. Look here for a decent run through of it:

https://webapplog.com/http2-server-push-node-express/

An example route from that page:

```
app.get('/pushy', (req, res) => {
  var stream = res.push('/main.js', {
    status: 200, // optional
    method: 'GET', // optional
    request: {
      accept: '*/*'
    },
    response: {
      'content-type': 'application/javascript'
    }
  })
  stream.on('error', function() {
  })
  stream.end('alert("hello from push stream!");')
  res.end('<script src="/main.js"></script>')
})
```

Calling `res.push()` is the key here with the file you want to serve.

He also documents a way to write some middleware to handle pushing as well of assets:

https://webapplog.com/http2-server-push-express-middleware/

Once you have this implemented you can see the pushed items in Chrome devtools as in the answer from BazzaDP.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome will show "Push / Other" in the Initiator column in Developer Tools->Network if the asset is pushed from the server:

[image]

I don't use the SDPY module in Node, but looks like from [here](https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy) and 
[here](https://github.com/ericallam/spdy-with-server-push-tutorial) that this module doesn't use the Link header to push resources like some other servers (e.g. Apache) do. So unless you have, for example, Apache in front of this in HTTP/2 mode then I doubt your code will push the resource.